# How to resolve mastodon toot URL's appearing in RSS to a specific instance?

Tags: rss, mastodon

When you obtain a toot timeline from a Mastodon instance using RSS, the RSS items do not point back to that instance. They all point to the instances which those toots originated from. This makes it very inconvenient to use RSS as a tool for consuming Mastodon toots and engaging with them. To reply to a toot or follow the user, you have to go through the inconvenient workflow of switching back to your home instance.  But your home instance served up that content in the first place?

I looked at the URLs to see whether they can be rewritten by pattern matching. Unfortunately, the numeric IDs are different.

Concretely, the RSS items contain URLS like this:

```
<ORIG_INSTANCE_DOMAIN>/@<USER>/<NUMERIC_ID_X>
```

The URL you want looks like this:

```
<YOUR_INSTANCE_DOMAIN>/@<USER>/@<ORIG_INSTANCE>/<NUMERIC_ID_Y>
```

The problem is that a rewrite is not possible: notice that the `NUMERIC_ID_X` and `NUMERIC_ID_Y` are different values.

How do solve this problem? Is there an API for this?

Better yet, is thera HTML (not JSON) API whereby we just feed some URL with parameters to the instance, and it serves up its own local view of that toot's thread?

Comment: I have the exact same question (see https://github.com/Riduidel/mastodon-rss/issues/7). If I find the answer, I'll notify you